# When I delete an object, are objects referenced within deleted as well?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, c++-cli, delete-operator

I have a main object. It holds a lot of arrays holding other objects. I wonder, when I delete the main object, will all the memory be released( main objects and the arrays and the objects(elements) of arrays )? For example:

```
Fruit^  my_fruit = gcnew Fruit;
Apple^  first_apple = gcnew Apple;
Apple^  second_apple = gcnew Apple;
my_fruit->AppleList->Add(first_apple);
my_fruit->AppleList->Add(second_apple);

// some operations

delete my_fruit; // **is it enough to avoid memory leak, is it necessary to delete first and second apple objects?**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Fruit and Apple objects are instantiated by gcnew, and your list is managed type as well, you won't need to call delete on the fruit object; the garbage collector will take care of it.

If on the other hand, say the list in the Fruit object was unmanaged type, then yes you would need explicit memory deallocation code to free the list since the garbage collector doesn't know or care about the memory allocated for that list.

The best practice would be to define a destructor for the Fruit class, and put the delete list code in there. The delete call to Fruit will automatically call the destructor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/248aa748(v=vs.80).aspx

(edited after Matt's correction)

Comment: thanks, that was helpful.. I really need to understand memory management.

Comment: This is not correct.  Delete will not free memory for these managed objects created with gcnew.  Unless these classes implement IDisposable, there is no need for delete calls.  Fruit would not require a destructor unless the AppleList implemented IDisposable (i.e. it has a destructor).

Comment: Ah yes, got confused. Since we are talking about gcnew it is handled by the garbage collector. If on the other hand you were using new instead, you would need to put in memory deallocating code to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The delete call will *not* release the memory.  Memory allocated with gcnew will be freed by the garbage collector (not by your call to delete).  Calling delete will call the destructor (which is analogous to Dispose in C#).  See the following:
http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/735989-gcnew
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/19e35d8c-94c2-4ea0-8e27-8e5cb94e898e/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197(VS.80).aspx

Comment: is there any way of deleting objects when I want?

Comment: Why do you want to?  The garbage collector will take care of it for you?  If you use native code, then you will be in control of the memory management yourself.

Comment: I do not use native code. I program process a lot of data, so I do not want to wait for the garbage collector. In about two hours,I will write my code and show you. There may be a problem about me.

Comment: If you want to use a managed language, then you get garbage collection way of reclaiming memory whether you want it or not.  I think the best you could do is to force garbage collection at a time that is convienent to you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx
But I would recommend against this.  "procesing a lot of data" is not necessarily a problem for the garbage collector.  Why don't you want to "wait for the garbage collector"?  If you really want/need to manually control memory lifetime, then a managed language is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a memory leak.  With managed types, memory is freed by the garbage collector (as Matt and sp1ky have already stated).  The `delete` keyword is used to *dispose* the object.

Using `delete` on a list will not dispose any objects contained inside that list.  However, you aren't using it on the list, but on the parent object.  So it depends on whether the parent object is written to automatically dispose its children.

Answer (score 0):

Except for quite unusual programs, garbage collection will happen "often enough" that there is no need to manually deallocate objects. The only problem you might have is if you are holding onto references to large objects longer than you need to.

e.g. If you load and process two huge collections in the same function, and you store them in two different variables, the variable holding the first collection will still be live when you process the second collection. If you don't actually need the first collection anymore, the garbage collector might not notice until you return from the function and then both collections go out of scope. That might not be soon enough if the two collections don't both fit into memory at the same time.

What you can do to address this is try to break up your code into smaller units, so that you don't hold on to references to things much longer than you need to. Sometimes you can't do that without destroying the logical structure of your code, but remember that you can always assign to a variable so that it no longer holds a reference to the large object, which will then be eligible for garbage collection.

This is a bit like manually deallocating the object, except that the garbage collector takes care of whatever else was referenced from that object for you, and you can code it the same way even if you can't be sure whether the object is needed elsewhere in the program. If you were managing the memory manually you would be forced to come up with some strategy for communicating whether the object is still needed, or keep it "just in case" (which would be a memory leak, as if no other part of the program *is* using it no one would ever free it). With the GC figuring that out for you, you just remove your reference and if the object is needed elsewhere it will stick around, and if not it will be removed some time soon.